# Alternative Django package for "django.core.xheaders" in Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-migrations

I'm migrating an old `Django` project to `Django 2.0`. In one of view files, I came across an `import` statement:

```
from django.core.xheaders import populate_xheaders
```

I'm trying to figure out the alternatives of this packages - neither in *google* nor in *stackoverflow*.

Can anyone help me find the alternative package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django.core.xheaders` was removed in Django 1.6. The following message was added to the docs upon its removal:

> The `django.contrib.flatpages` app used to set custom HTTP headers for
>   debugging purposes. This functionality was not documented and made caching
>   ineffective so it has been removed, along with its generic implementation,
>   previously available in `django.core.xheaders`.

I suspect you may be able to remove the call to this function in the app you're porting.

If you *do* need these headers, you could copy the functionality from [the commit where it was removed](https://github.com/django/django/commit/64e11a68f19793d11915e83574b1bb693da3980e#diff-5ead48f8f97dc086ba68649c78b5038bL12).

For information on why this function was initially created, consult [the ticket that tracked its addition](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2581).